# Footer doesn't stay on bottom of page when not enough content is displayed

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade, tailwind-css

I know this question gets asked often, I already googled a lot but did not find a solution.

I am trying to place my footer at the bottom of the page all the time, so even when not enough content is in the page.

Here is my `app.blade.php` code: (I shortened it a bit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Finanzraketen</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    <style>
        .hintergrund {
            background-image: url('/background.jpeg');
            background-size: cover;

        }
    </style>
</head>


<body class="hintergrund pb-18">
<!-- Navbar goes here -->
<nav class="bg-white shadow-lg bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 mb-10 h-20">
    <div class="max-w-full mx-auto px-4">
        <div class="flex justify-between">
            <div class="flex space-x-0">
                
                <!-- Primary Navbar items -->
                <div class="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-3">
                    <ul class="flex items-center pl-2 grid grid-cols-8 gap-2">

                        <a class="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition text-sm border-2 border-black border-opacity-20 text-center
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100"
                           href="{{ route('overview') }}">Stellenanzeigen</a>


                        @auth('web')
                            <a class="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition text-sm border-2 border-black border-opacity-20 text-center
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100"
                               href="{{ route('alle_bewerbungen') }}">Bewerbungen</a>


</nav>
@yield('content')
<footer class="bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 opacity-60 p-4 relative w-full">
<div class="bg-light py-4">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <p class="text-muted mb-0 py-2">© 2019 Bootstrapious All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried tinkering with the tailwind position attributes, so `absolute, relative` etc. I tried `inset-x-0 bottom-0` and nothing works.

I read every SO question I could find about it but nothing seems to work.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

give to your main div `min-height: 100vh;` and then your footer put on the bottom section.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Either use a min-height for your body or main element. Like AkifObaidi suggested - as in:

```
body{ min-height: 80vh; } /* adapt to your needs - what is the least high page, test it out there */
```

Or you go with a position:fixed footer - making it stick to the bottom of your viewport, not the page:

```
footer{ position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; }
```